# How to specify div element within wrapper

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the following script, but I have placed the 'tab-prev' and 'tab-next' buttons inside a div that is inside the .tab-wrapper, I can't work out how to select them inside that div?

```
<script>  
var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {

$('.tab-wrapper’).on('click', '.tab-prev, .tab-next', function() {

var direction = $(this).hasClass('tab-prev') ? -1 : 1;

var tablinks = $(this).parent().find('.w-tab-menu');

var index = tablinks.find('.w--current').index() + direction;

index = index >= tablinks.children().length ? 0 : index;

tablinks.find('.w-tab-link').eq(index).trigger('click');

   });
 });
</script>
```

And html example

```
<div class=“wrapper”>
    <div class=“w-tab-menu”>
         <a data-w-tab="Tab 1" class="w-tab-link">
         <a data-w-tab="Tab 2" class="w-tab-link">
    </div>
    <div class=“w-tab-panes”>
         <div data-w-tab="Tab 1" class="w-tab-pane">
         <div data-w-tab="Tab 2" class="w-tab-pane">
    </div>
    <div class=“bottom-buttons”>
         <a href="" class="tab-prev">Prev</a>
         <a href="" class="tab-next">Next</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$('.tab-wrapper').find('.tab-prev')` doesnt work ?

Comment: Nope, but I'm probably not doing it correctly. I thought it would be a matter of specifying that the buttons were now inside a child div, something like`$('.tab-wrapper > .bottom-buttons ’)`

Comment: i mean you can even just do `$('.tab-prev')` to make sure its working in general

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this to select prev and next buttons:

```
var $prev = $('.tab-prev');
var $next = $('.tab-next');
```